# ember.js - reference a variable from another variable function in the same controller

Tags: javascript, variables, ember.js, controller

So I have a user's brands controller which has 2 variables - user_brands, remaining_brands. User_brands are the brands that the user has favorited and remaining_brands are the brands that the user could potentially favorite.

```
user_brands: function(){
    var self = this, brands;

    Ember.$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/user_favourites',
        success: function(response){
            brands = response["brands"];
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
        }
    });

    return brands;
}.property('user_brands'),

remaining_brands: function(){
    var self = this, remaining_brands;

    Ember.$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/brands',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(self.get('user_brands')); //trying to reference user_brands defined above
            remaining_brands = response["brands"];
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
        }
    });

    return remaining_brands;
}.property('remaining_brands')
```

So to get 'remaining_brands', I'm trying to get every brand possible and subtract it by 'user_brands' so that duplicates don't show up if the user has already added a brand. How do I correctly reference the user_brands function?

Comment: You cannot return a variable `brands` which doesn't exist yet because it's still waiting for the Ajax call to finish.

Comment: I see what you mean. So is there a way to call the user_brands function inside remaining_brands? Or something along those lines.